# mysql order of escapes and order of operations

Tags: mysql

I'm running a query on a table that contains values, some of the form "jsFunc('H:\\directory\\subdir\\whatever.ext')", others of the form "jsFunc('\\\\ServerName\\directory\\subdir\\whatever.ext')" along many other random strings items.

I want to select anything with the form "H:\\directory\\subdir"

heres my query...

```
SET @s = 'H:\\\\directory';
SELECT * FROM 'db'.'table' WHERE column LIKE CONCAT('%',@s,'%')
```

which produces no results. I've tried this without the variable/concat.

some values that produce results, and some that do not(but I feel they should)

```
@s = 'H:';              /*   returned rows*/
@s = 'H:\\';            /*no returned rows*/
@s = 'H:\\\\';          /*   returned rows*/
@s = 'H:\\\\directory'; /*no returned rows*/

@s = '\\\\directory';           /*   returned rows*/
@s = '\\\\directory\\\\subdir'; /*no returned rows*/

/* and worse of all... */

@s = 'H:\\\\directory\\\\subdir'; /*no returned rows. these are the rows I want*/
```

At first I thought the order of escaping operations might be causing the problem, hence the concatted '%' to make sure they were not being escaped, but there doesn't seem to be a difference. Is there some sort of escape voodoo going on here that I am missing?

Comment: are you storing a literal `H:\\etc...`? What's the data look like when you manually select without a where clause?

Comment: Yes, stored as a double slash, they are string literal arguments for javascript calls, so they need to be in the form of escaped slashes after the query completes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u should just do `@s = 'H:\\'; select @s;`
then u would realized u need to double + double escape in order to achieve the like search
`string H:\\ => H:\\\\\\\\`

Comment: hmm.. ok, I've got %H:\\\\\\\\DIRECTORY\\\\\\\\subdir% which works correctly... I initially only read the docs on strings (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html) and skimmed/skipped over the note pointing at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html which indicates strings to be used in comparisons are parsed differently. Unfortunately your answer is correct, but your example is incorrect, you have 2 slashes => 6 slashes. If you change it to 8, I will accept. Thanks

Comment: @Peta - eagle eye ..also, consider the `quote()` function

Comment: also @s = 'H:\\'; select @s lends no insight, as the rules for escaping in a pattern differ from those for defining strings

Comment: @Peta - surpsing, `select @s;` actual return H:\

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE ('%%H:\\directory\\subdir%%')